# Bibliography title issue

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning

I have a problem with automatically `\bibliography{}`-command titling.

Latex assumes that title makes as `\section{*}\\ References`, but `\section*{References}` is needed.

Here is the picture of the problem
[image]

Here is Style file

```
\ProvidesPackage{chsu}[2019/08/16 chsu Style Package]
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm} %различные математические пакеты

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} %кодировка символов
\RequirePackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc} %кодировка шрифтов (T1 - латин, T2A - кирил)
\RequirePackage[english,russian]{babel} %русский и английский языки в документе, переносы

\RequirePackage[
    left=2.5cm,
    right=1.5cm,
    top=2cm,
    bottom=2cm
]{geometry} %поля страницы

\RequirePackage{setspace} %для разных разметок
\onehalfspacing %полуторный интерлиньяж

\RequirePackage{indentfirst} %первая строка абзаца всегда красная
\parindent = 1.25cm %абзацный отступ

\RequirePackage{enumitem} %пакет для списков
\setlist[enumerate,itemize]{leftmargin=1.87cm,nosep,noitemsep} %списки выравниваются по абзацу
\renewcommand\labelitemi{---} %вместо точки у списков будет тире

\RequirePackage{color} %цвета в pdf (для ссылок)
\RequirePackage[pdfhighlight=/I,colorlinks=true]{hyperref} %ссылки в pdf
\RequirePackage[all]{hypcap} %по ссылке переносит на рисунок, а не название
\RequirePackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} %добавляет библиографию в содержание

\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{0pt}
        {1.3pt}
        {1.3pt}
        {\centering\hyphenpenalty=10000\normalfont\bfseries}
} % заголовок по ГОСТ

\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{0pt}
        {1.3pt}
        {1.3pt}
        {\centering\hyphenpenalty=10000\normalfont\bfseries}
} % подзаголовок по ГОСТ

\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{0pt}
        {1.3pt}
        {1.3pt}
        {\centering\hyphenpenalty=10000\normalfont\bfseries}
} % подподзаголовок по ГОСТ

\def\capfigure{figure} %заменяет знак в названии рисунка точку на тире
\def\captable{table}
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \ifx\@captype\capfigure
      \centering #1~---~#2 \par
  \else
      #1~---~#2 \par
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}

\addto\captionsrussian{\def\figurename{Рисунок}} %вместо рис. - рисунок (ГОСТ)
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}} %сквозная нумерация рисунков

\newtheoremstyle{forthm} %стиль для теорем
    {0em}
    {0em}
    {\itshape}
    {1.25cm}
    {\bfseries}
    { \normalfont{---} }
    {0em}
    {}

\theoremstyle{forthm} %обозначение, что теоремы будут с этим стилем
\newtheorem{theorem}{Теорема}[section] %команда для теоремы        
\newtheorem{lemmma}{Лемма}[section] %команда для леммы

\newtheoremstyle{fordefn} %стиль для определений
    {0em}
    {0em}
    {}
    {1.25cm}
    {\bfseries}
    { \normalfont{---} }
    {0em}
    {}
\theoremstyle{fordefn} %обозначение, что определения будут с этим стилем
\newtheorem{definition}{Определение}[section] %команда для определения
\newtheorem{prop}{Утверждение}[section] %команда для утверждения

\newcommand{\hm}[1]{#1\nobreak\discretionary{}{\hbox{\ensuremath{#1}}}{}}       %команда делает повторение символа в строчной формуле

\endinput
```

Comment: Can you show us a full example document that actually prints a bibliography and reproduces the issue you are seeing, please? (An MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) We need to know which packages you use for your bibliography and how it is produced to be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reduced MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{0pt}
        {1.3pt}
        {1.3pt}
        {\centering\hyphenpenalty=10000\normalfont\bfseries}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section*{Foo}
\end{document}
```

reproduces the issue you describe

[image: 1 *//Foo]

The problem here is a spurious space at the end of the redefinition of `\section`. The unprotected end-of-line character will produce an unwanted space that wreaks havoc on your headlines if you use the starred form. A correct definition would be

```
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{0pt}
        {1.3pt}
        {1.3pt}
        {\centering\hyphenpenalty=10000\normalfont\bfseries}}
```

or

```
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{0pt}
        {1.3pt}
        {1.3pt}
        {\centering\hyphenpenalty=10000\normalfont\bfseries}%
}
```

All of the `\section`-like commands in `chsu` are affected and need to be fixed. If at all possible, please report this bug to the maintainer of the class/package.

With the fixed version the result is

[image: Foo]

as expected.